# Existence of a homeomorphism between two spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider $ S = {(u,v,x,y) \in \Bbb R^4 | (u^2 + v^2 - a)^2 + x^2 + y^2 - b = 1 }$ $  a>b>1$. I have to prove or disprove whether this is homeomorphic to $(S^1)^3$, where $S^1$ is the unit circle. My guess is that these are not homeomorphic. The fundamental group of $(S^1)^3$ is the product of $\Bbb Z$ three times. It seems to me that $S$ is very similar to the torus $(S^1)^2$ since the description of $S$ is very close to the parametrization of the torus. The fundamental group of the torus is the product of $\Bbb Z$ two times. Hence, they should not be homeomorphic. But I am not being able to rigorously find the fundamental group of $S$.

Comment: $S$ seems to be a Spheritorus: http://hi.gher.space/wiki/Spheritorus tough the equation is not totally the same. (And it's weird that I got $S$ not being smooth manifold. Maybe I did something wrong)